# Unbreakable code and mathematical impossibility

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, brute-force-attack

Is an unbreakable code  mathematically possible , considering a code with finite number of characters but has infinite combinations , using brute force is it not compulsory that the correct code be found in a finite time ?

Comment: codes are no security measure.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it's possible – it's called a [one-time-pad](/questions/tagged/one-time-pad).

How it works is you have a truly random keystream of bits as long as the message. Every bit is $0$ or $1$ with exactly 50% probability each. Every bit is truly independent from every other bit and all possible keystreams of the same length are equally likely. When you XOR (exclusive-or) it with the message, the result is the ciphertext.

You *can't* brute-force it, because literally every possible message having the same length as the ciphertext is an equally likely to produce a correct decryption result (a message is just as likely to be *“Infiltrate commandos”* as *“How was your holiday”*). Sure, you could try all possible keys using a brute-force attack… but that merely produces a collection of strings of appropriate length where each of them could be a potentially correct decryption result. It has been mathematically proven that you have just as much ability to break an OTP without the ciphertext as with it.

Comment: Good, but there is some inaccuracy. You can guess the probability from the context, so some messages are likely to have higher probability than others. However, the ciphertext does not give you more information than the length of the plaintext. Having the length of the plaintext, you can guess exactly the same.

Comment: Padding before encryption with the one-time-pad defeats knowing the length of the plaintext.

Comment: @SAI: In fact it's really easy. Copy the rest of the pad (might be the same as encrypting AAAAAA). Interceptor can't tell the difference and the pad will not be reused anyway.AAAAAAAAAAAAA